# Is there any standard which defines that a particular connector or header on PCB has to be male or female?

Tags: connector, standard, header, db9

Is there any standard which defines that connector (DB9, DB25, USB or header) type  has to be MALE or FEMALE while choosing one to use on circuit board?
 I am designing a microcontroller circuit board for general use.

Comment: No.  However, standards for some interfaces may dictate the connector choice based on a device's role, ie, a fixed function USB host should be an "A" connector, etc.

Comment: Presumably a correct answer would be an example of such a standard? What do you actually want to know?

Comment: A "standard" (guideline?) I've seen is that the connector with power or data is often female, because there are no exposed pins to corrode or short.  The cable is often seen as more disposable than the device.  Think computer peripherals like monitors, PS/2, LPT, and so on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Often the connector side that is "live", having voltage present on it while not plugged in, will be female/sockets and the mating half will obviously be male/pins. It reduces the chance of shock or shorting. Small signal stuff doesn't matter so much, but with power connectors it's more important to keep live contacts inaccessible.